# Adding a border to a Google PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, autocomplete

I am using a Google Places Autocomplete fragment in an Android app.  When I use the fragment directly in the top level of a LinearLayout, everything works:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/findRidePlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This layout leads to this UI:

[image]

As you can see, there is no border around the widget, whereas the TextView below it has a black border.  From what I read, one trick to get a border around a fragment is to embed that fragment within a CardView.  This method is actually recommended by Google's [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete).  Consider the following modified layout:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/main_border">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/findRidePlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The trick here is to give the CardView a background with the Google Places fragment above it, such that the former will appear as a border around the latter.

But this modified layout causes the app to crash.  Does anyone know why this is crashing, or how I might place a border around a Google `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` ?

Comment: Could you post the logcat error?

Comment: Where do I find the error output?  I'm new to Android development.

Comment: You can find it on Android Studio under the ***Android Monitor*** tab, and there on the ***logcat*** tab, or you can type `adb logcat` on a command line or terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom background for the enclosing `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/main_border">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/findRidePlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using the same `android:background="@drawable/main_border"` that you have defined for your `CardView`. In my case `main_border.xml` (which lives on the `res/drawable` folder) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Currently my `LinearLayout` has other widgets in it.  Hut I will still try this and get back to you.

Comment: Have you tried this? The idea is not adding the background to the existing `LinearLayout` but replacing your `CardView` with the `LinearLayout` with the background

Comment: Everything in this activity already sits within a `LinearLayout`.  Are you suggesting putting a `LinearLayout` inside the one which is already there?

Comment: Yes, I suggest to substitute your `CardView` with a `LinearLayout`

Comment: Hi Antonio, your solution worked well, as least it works brilliantly so far.  Even if there are limitations to nested a LinearLayout within another LinearLayout, I don't see any problems and in any case your answer should be useful to at least some people who are struggling to put a border around this Google widget.

Comment: Google should update their documentation in my opinion.